# Running Airflow on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-colaboratory

I'm a beginner and trying to get familiar to Airflow. I'm following this tutorial to setup a local jobs : https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-airflow-df1aa77d7b1b

For a fast learning experience without too much time setting up, I decided to use Google Colab.

However I'm stuck after

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

The installation shows no error, however I cant call any airflow function. For example, a quick:

```
airflow version
```

returns

```
  File "<ipython-input-21-57277b57f744>", line 1
    airflow version
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There seems to be no other discussion on the same combination of colab and airflow (since it doesnt make much sense I guess, however Im just trying to get a quick learning experience) .I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Generally you should only use Colab notebooks for visualizing and exploring data. But I tried installing and setting up airflow on it and it seemed to work. First I ran `!pip install apache-airflow` and then `!airflow initdb`, and I could correctly verify the version by running `!airflow version`. Make sure that you prepend "!" to every bash command.

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I tried `!airflow webserver -p 8080` but it doesn't seem to connect

Comment: I'm attempting to get it work. It seems that you have to use ngrok to check access the webapp, still stuck on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the syntax vars(airflow) but first make sure you have installed and import airflow. to install airflow in colab use !pip install apache-airflow and to import airflow use import airflow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH4Mu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to call `airflow` or check version is like the following:

```
import airflow
airflow.__version__
```

Output:

```
2.8.0
```